# How to explain this step of solving a limit

Tags: limits

Can you help me with the steps getting to the right side from the left of the equation.

[image: logarithm equation]

Comment: Why dont you use Mathematica with Debug/Trace turned on?

Comment: This is just l'Hospital's rule:  Take the ratio of the derivative of the numerator and the derivative of the denominator on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f[x_] = (1 - 3^(1/x))/(1 + 3^(1/x));

Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> {x == 0}]
```

[image]

From the documentation for `Limit`,

> `Direction -> -1` takes variables to approach their limits by
>   decreasing from larger values.

```
Limit[f[x], x -> 0, Direction -> -1]
```

> -1

Using `WolframAlpha` from within *Mathematica*,

```
WolframAlpha["Limit[(1-3^(1/x))/(1+3^(1/x)), x -> 0, Direction -> -1]", 
  {{"Limit", 2}, "Content"}, PodStates -> {"Limit__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image]